# Using the duplicated SWIG module name

Tags: c++, module, lua, swig

I have a SWIG binding module called 'my'.

I generated the CPP binding file using SWIG.

Is it possible to generate another CPP binding file that uses the same module name?

I tried it anyway but I get the following errors.

```
duplicate symbol _luaopen_my
duplicate symbol __Z15luaopen_my_userP9lua_State
duplicate symbol _luaopen_my_luacode
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: That's not possible.  How is the (dynamic) linker supposed to know which `luaopen_my` symbol you want?

Comment: Maybe you are interested in this question: [Is it possible to split a SWIG module for compilation, but rejoin it when linking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697749/is-it-possible-to-split-a-swig-module-for-compilation-but-rejoin-it-when-linkin)